# Can glob be used with boolean searches?

Tags: unix, glob

I am hoping someone can help me. I am trying to use glob to find a filename. I want to find a file name that contains a 2 OR a 4 as the fifth character in the file name. For example, I want to write a glob that would find these file names:

```
00002.txt  
00004.txt  
12002.txt
```

I understand that I could use glob to find these files using a series such as:

```
ls ????[2-4]*
```

However, the above glob would also match files that had a 3 as the fifth character. Does anyone know how to glob for only files that contain a 2 OR 4 as the fifth character? Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: @khachik That should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `[24]` will allow just 2 or 4, instead of the range `[2-4]`, giving you:

```
ls ????[24]*
```